# Timeline apps? custom apps possible?

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, timeline

Is it possible to develop my own app which can be insert in the timeline or are there only 3rd party apps possible?

thx Karl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u want your application to post something to facebook wal its possible. The same gets into the timeline too. For more info visit facebook developers network